# Jquery rest api post call

Tags: jquery

i have a requirement to develop the chrome extension, in that i need to post the product information using the REST API Service, below is the URL

```
https://ABCD.com/api/products/?token=XXXXf&product[name]=Headphones&product[price]=100&product[permalink]=headphones1
```

getting the response when directly place in browser..

but i need to post this via JQuery ajax post call.. i tried some ways but no luck..

**My attempt:**

```
var product = [{ "name": "128.3657142857143", "price": "7", "permalink": "headphones1"}];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "URL",
        // The key needs to match your method's input parameter (case-sensitive).
        data: JSON.stringify({ token: 'XXXX', product: product }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert(data); },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

**Post call**

var product = [{ "name": "128.3657142857143", "price": "7", "permalink": "headphones1"}];

```
$.post("URL", JSON.stringify({ token: 'XXXX', product: product }),
  function (data) {
      alert('success');
  }
);
```

**ERROR**
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ***URL***. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

kindly help me out in how to form the jquery ajax call

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: edited the question again.. kindly revisit the question again

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) API reference.

Thirty char limit.

However, more importantly, you need to make sure that you've given your chrome extension permission to access that domain (whatever.herokuapp.com).

Comment: is my way of ajax post is ok?

Comment: It would be much easier if you used $.post(url, data)

Comment: i tried that as well, but not worked. Anyway i will try again

Comment: i tried, but same error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://smooth-journey-6300.herokuapp.com/api/products. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". please revisit my question..

Comment: Okay, got it. You need to fix your permissions. Check this out: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: but i tried in normal html page + Jquery call (not inside extension).. still it is not working. do we need to provide permission for this as well?

Comment: You can't use it inside a normal HTML page - cross origin requests are forbidden on browsers. You need you set the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a while ago so it's probably not relavant anymore, however !

To it seems like you don't want a POST at all, you want a GET instead.

Because:

1. It works when you enter the URL in the address bar (which is a GET)
2. The URL has correct GET query data

With the following on this page in the console:

```
var data = { 
  token: 'XXXX', 
  product: { "name": "128.3657142857143", "price": "7", "permalink": "headphones1"}
}

$.get('/', data);
```

Then checking the network requests, I see:

```
GET http://stackoverflow.com/?token=XXXX&product[name]=128.3657142857143&product[price]=7&product[permalink]=headphones1
```